# Speech Recognition Python stuck here

Tags: python-3.x

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listening = sr.Recognizer()

try:

    with sr.Microphone() as src:

        print("listening...")

        voice = listening.listen(src)    #Program stuck at here with no error and not moving to next line

        cmd = listening.recognize_google(voice)

        print(cmd)

except:

    print("Error...")
```

Comment: It could be that the recognizer tries to recognize speech even when you aren't speaking, or after you are done speaking. So try increasing the recognizer_instance.energy_threshold property. This is basically how sensitive the recognizer is to when recognition should start. Higher values mean that it will be less sensitive, which is useful if you are in a loud room.

Source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try this:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

listening = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("listening...")

    listening.pause_threshold=1

    voice = listening.listen(source)    

    try:

        print("Recognizing....")
        cmd = listening.recognize_google(voice, language='en-in')
        print(cmd)
    except Exception as e:

        print("Error...")
```

Comment: It's also not working and still stuck on listening